# How to show CPU percentage number in system tray (taskbar) on Windows 11 (with free app)?

Tags: windows-11

I am a new Windows user. (I come from the Linux world).

I would like to show the real-time CPU percentage number (NOT a CU graph) in the system tray (taskbar) on Windows 11.

How can I achieve this? Any free app is OK. I won't install any paid app.

Btw, I also need to show CPU temperature number in the system tray. So far, I am using Speccy. But the number looks very ugly with a yellow foreground and black background. I am wondering if anyone can suggest an app which uses a black foreground and no background color (transparent background color).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I found [HWiNFO](https://www.hwinfo.com/download/) which is pretty good. It's kinda hard to use, but it supports all sensors and very advanced customization on all kinds of things. It can add anything to the system tray icons on the taskbar. If nobody has a better option, I will stay with it. Thanks a lot.